# Is it possible to write a language parser with AWK?

Tags: linux, parsing, unix, awk

I just recently started reading up on the ***AWK*** ***programming language***, with the intent of creating a programming language parser with it, since it is generally used as a Text processor and/or for pattern matching. I had the thought, "If this language is used for pattern matching, and processing text, couldn't it be used to process a source file for specific statements such as for / if / while keywords and phrases, and then perform the given action, and pass it off to a lexer, or something of the sort?" I've done some research online, but i'm unable to find any kind of information on this subject.

Comment: Awk is turing complete, so it *can* be used for any programming problem (within reason). However, it is unlikely to be the best tool for this usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK can be used to create Language grammars when you combine it with other Linux/Unix tools such as sed and shell (BASH/KSH) programming.  Typically though other tools are better suited like python, Groovy, Perl, or GO.  Each of these languages are better suited to language processing than AWK.

Answer (score 1):

In some respects, awk is essentially a lexer.

If you want C-like character stream parsing with awk, you can alter field separator and record separator values in awk to suit your needs.  Quite reasonably, the field separator variable is FS, and the record separator variable is RS.